# Undesired frame around image on MFC C++

Tags: c++, image, mfc

I'm trying to display an image on a MFC dialog (c++).

If I display a jpg, everything works right but with a png with transparent areas the result is different.

I'm using a png image that should only be black and transparent but there's a white frame around it and on some other areas too.

This is the code I'm using:

```
CDC *pDC;
pDC = this->GetDC();
HDC hdc = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
CImage image;
image.Load( ".//home.png" );
image.Draw(hdc , 50, 50);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Any ideas?

Btw, should I release pDC in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to do it:

```
CDC *pDC;
pDC = this->GetDC();
HDC hdc = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
Gdiplus::Graphics G(hdc);
Gdiplus::Image I(L".//home.png");
G.DrawImage(&I,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using transparency requires the use of "pre-multiplied" images.  Essentially, run through the image pixels (look at `GetBits()`) once before first use and convert each pixel by component something like:

```
c[0] = (unsigned char)( (unsigned int)c[0] * (unsigned int)c[3] / 255 );
c[1] = (unsigned char)( (unsigned int)c[1] * (unsigned int)c[3] / 255 );
c[2] = (unsigned char)( (unsigned int)c[2] * (unsigned int)c[3] / 255 );
```

you can search the net for some examples.